# AngularJs how to run angularjs on local server? and Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to write a small web application: listing user name and number

Those files are in the same folder, for example:

```
ang8
  |----  index.html
  |----  list.html
  |----  contacts.js
```

When I am trying to open index.html, it does not load the content in list.html. 
Any idea?? Thanks!

The index.html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="contacts">
    <meta character="utf-8">
    <title>Contacts</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * { box-sizing: border-box; }
        body { font: 14px/1.5 sans-serif; color: #222; margin: 3em;}
    </style>

    <div ng-controller="Contacts">
        <h1>Contacts</h1>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="contacts.js"></script>
</html>
```

The list.html code:

```
<h2>List</h2>
<div>
    <label>search: </label><input type="search" ng-model="search">
    <br>
</div>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:search">
        <a href="#/contact/{{$index}}">{{contact.name}}</a>
        : {{contact.number}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the js code:

```
angular
    .module('contacts', [])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'list.html'
            });
    })
    .controller('Contacts', function($scope){
        $scope.contacts = [
            {name: 'Tom', number: '1234'},
            {name: 'David', number: '4321'},
            {name: 'Jason', number: '12345'}
        ];
    })
```

Comment: Where are you including the source for `ngRoute`?

Comment: @Asok sorry, there is no ngRoute, type mistake

Comment: So you are still getting the injection error without `ngRoute`, correct? Just making sure. Actually, if I am correct you need `ngRoute` to access `$routeProvider`, so you could either reference ngRoute or remove your $routeProvider and you should be fine

Comment: If there's no `ngRoute` why are you injecting `$routeProvider`?

Comment: @Asok yes, initially, without ngRoute, does not work, then tried adding ngRoute, still not working

Comment: Both `ng-view` and `$routeProvider` is in the `ngRoute` module. So either you have to add the dependency and .js reference, or you have to remove both.

Comment: I have updated my answer guy's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular can't find the `ngRoute` dependency. You're missing a reference to `angular-route(.min).js`. Add the following line below the `angular.min.js` reference:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: And BTW, you're missing the `controller: 'Contacts'` in your route declaration :)

Comment: To add to @khellang's last comment, he is correct, the controller can and should really be declared in the route config, which means you wouldn't really need any controller declaration in the html, unless you were nesting controllers of course