# New to web development and do not know how to run angularjs on localhost?

Tags: angularjs

Folks - I am novice in web development and to AngularJS as well. Just trying to run a simple basic app which has 'home' and 'about us'. Please help me understand  how to run this simple app on localhost on some port. Below is my file structure:

```
Root(app folder)
-- index.html
-- pages (folder)
-- js/fonts/css (all bootstrap folder)
-- bower_components (folder)
```

Appreciate if you can let me know the exact steps to run this code locally.

After searching a lot online, I understood that there has to be server.js. But not sure how.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJs how to run angularjs on local server? and Uncaught Error: \[$injector:modulerr\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070145/angularjs-how-to-run-angularjs-on-local-server-and-uncaught-error-injectorm)

Comment: You can search for the similar issues on stackoverflow, there are many related topics already answered. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Rahul! I am searching on other blogs as well in this website.